# Windows Server 2016 V3 Printers (GhostScript)

Tags: windows, redirect, printing, server

I'm setting up printer redirection ports in Windows Server 2016, I've tried setting up a few different class version types of printers, such as V2, V3 and V4, all being color printers.

I'm running into an issue where the printer driver isn't compatible with port redirection, using both GhostScript and Redmon.

Does anyone have suggestions for this, or a list of supported printers?

Kind regards,

Worst case scenario I'll need to change the way this project saves PDFs.

Comment: AIUI Microsoft changed the printer pipeline significantly in Windows 8 and 10. I believe Port Monitors (which is what RedMon is) no longer work. Its possible that older printer drivers use some kind of legacy mode which allows them to continue working, but obviously that's going to disappear over time. This isn't really a Ghostscript question; Ghostscript doesn't do anything with ports on its own.

Comment: Hi @KenS, Thanks for your reply. I managed to solve the issue, by selecting the Ghostscript PDF driver as the printer driver. All other settings were as per normal in accordance to the Ghostscript documentation.

Thanks you,